# Reading data via AJAX call or MYSQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, json, web

Context: I am creating a website where I will need to show statistics. The statistics are calculated in Python and I need a place to store the calculated stats so it can be read and be presented in the website. The statistics are calculated by going through around 70000 JSON files so the calculations are done beforehand. The data is not dynamic so all I need to do is just read the data and therefore there is no writing or changing the data.

Solutions:

MySQL approach: I put the statistics in the DB beforehand and use PHP to connect to the MYSQL database and use SELECT statements to get the data and present it.

AJAX (JavaScript) approach: I put the statistics I need into a JSON file and put the file into my server. I use an AJAX call to get the JSON data and parse it and show the statistics from JavaScript.

Question: Which would be the best approach to take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If speed is top priority, PHP/MYSQL is definitely faster.

With AJAX, I assume that your 70,000 JSON files are split up, and your AJAX call queries the "right one". Depending on your client, the user experience might be nicer since you can get new data without doing a page refresh.

One "happy medium" solution could be do make an ajax call to a `query.php` file which does the MySQL/PHP lookup, but returns a JSON object so that you can get the best of both worlds!

Answer (score 0):

use the php/mysql approach

why

- faster
- doesn't consume a lot of resources on the client side and doesn't slow the browser.